# Animate Glass BSDF Index of Refraction over Time?

Tags: animation, materials, properties, glass

Is there a way to animate the index of refraction of a glass material so that it will change from say 1.1 at frame 10 to 1.8 at frame 30?

Answer (score 1):

Have you keyframed them? Go to frame 10 in the timeline, set the IOR to 1.1, right-click the IOR, click "insert keyframe." Go to frame 30, set the IOR to 1.8, and insert the keyframe again.

Comment: you can also hover over the value and press **i** to insert a keyframe.

Comment: @Millard Huh. I didn't know that shortcut existed.